# Запуск Web-приложения на java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, servlet

Сделал проект по примеру - [ссылка](http://devcolibri.com/1043)

Дошел до шага - №6

Запускаю, вроде все норм, но http://localhost:8080/s - не работает!

В чем причина?

Лог:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:53234,suspend=y,server=n -Xmx512m -Dmaven.home=C:\apache-maven-3.2.5 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin\m2.conf -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=14.0.2
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53234', transport: 'socket'
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for ru:test:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 39, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ test ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ test ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\sanu0074\IdeaProjects\test\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ test ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\sanu0074\IdeaProjects\test\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ test ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [test] in [C:\Users\sanu0074\IdeaProjects\test\target\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\sanu0074\IdeaProjects\test\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [26 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\sanu0074\IdeaProjects\test\target\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ test ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\sanu0074\IdeaProjects\test\target\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to C:\Users\sanu0074\.m2\repository\ru\test\1.0-SNAPSHOT\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\sanu0074\IdeaProjects\test\pom.xml to C:\Users\sanu0074\.m2\repository\ru\test\1.0-SNAPSHOT\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.185s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Apr 26 17:03:10 EEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53234', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте следующие адреса:

- http://localhost:8080/test/s
- http://localhost:8080/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/s

По умолчанию приложение разворачивается в субдиректории с названием вашего проекта, для того чтобы это изменить, нужно отредактировать `server.xml`. Можно прочитать об этом в очень похожей на вашу [ветке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat)

Comment: Проблема в порту 1099, пишет что он гдетото используется, но это не так, я их пробовал менять, толку ноль(

Comment: @sanu0074 попробуйте перезапустить среду и томкат. Проверьте в процессах, не запущена ли еще одна копия tomcat.exe. В Intellij Idea можно запустить несколько проектов, зайдите в меню `Run` > `Stop` должно быть неактивно. Если `Stop` активно, значит, одна или несколько копий приложения сейчас запущено. Если и это не помогло, попробуйте решить как здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085371/tomcat-intellij-idea-remote-deploy